# jquery autosuggest doesn't work on mobile

Tags: jquery, flask, autosuggest

I have a flask app which uses jquery autosuggest for user input. This works perfectly on any desktop device, but doesn't on mobile devices (android, iOS). Here is the code:

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

<script type=text/javascript>
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("input[id^='autocomplete_temp']").autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("{{url_for('autocomplete')}}",{
                query: request.term, 
                pagetype: 'temperatures',
            }, function(data) {
                response(data.matching_results); 
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Here is the form:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <form action="{{ url_for('parse_request', type='results_temperature') }}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete_temp1" class="form-control" placeholder="City 1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="city1"></input>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete_temp2" class="form-control" placeholder="City 2" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="city2"></input>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete_temp3" class="form-control" placeholder="City 3" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="city3"></input>
        <p class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit!</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

And lastly, the python function:

```
@app.route('/autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    q = request.args.get('query')
    pagetype = request.args.get('pagetype')

    if pagetype == 'temperatures':
        df = pd.read_csv(path_temp, sep="\t", index_col=[0])
        filtered = filter(lambda x: q in x.lower().decode("utf-8"), df.index)

    return jsonify(matching_results=filtered)
```

As I said, it all works file on desktop, but when I type anything on mobile, no auto-suggest list appears.

Things I tried before posting the question:

1. Deleting cookies and browsing history in my phone
2. Trying on multiple smartphones and tablets
3. Removing bootstrap styling from input tags and leaving bare `<input type="text" id="autocomplete_temp1" placeholder="City 1" name="city1">`  in case there was some conflict there
4. Checking if jquery works on my smartphone at all, I inserted a dummy jquery code which [takes two numbers and adds them](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/), this worked, so jquery loads fine
5. I simulated mobile user agent using developer tools in on desktop Google Chrome, autosuggest worked
6. I experimented importing different, newer versions (1.12.0) of the jquery CDN, namely:

   code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

   code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js

   code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js

None of this helped or got me closer to solving this. Any hints are greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: I would suggest trying to remotely debug the page on your Android Chrome browser using the Remote Debugging feature => https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Great tip, thank you! Remote debugging showed that the problem was not using `.lower()` on user input. As on a mobile device user input is capitalized by default, no matches were found. When I tested it on desktop it worked, as the query was typed all in lowercase.

Comment: Glad to be of help :-)